# How can I change the position of the gridlines without changing the position of the label axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello is there a way to change the grid positions without also changing the label position of the axis?
I would like to leave the position of the labels as it normally appears without specifying but with the lines of the grid in a specifief position.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# yvals = [floats]
# list_of_points = [[(x,y), (x,y), (x,y), ...], [...], ...]

ax.plot([i for i in range(len(y_vals))], y_vals, label=y_name)

for points, points_name in zip(list_of_points, list_of_points_names):
    xpoints = [v[0] for v in points]
    ypoints = [v[1] for v in points]
    ax.scatter(xpoints, ypoints, label=points_name)

points = []
for p in list_of_points:
    points += p

ax.set_xticks([p[0] for p in points])
ax.set_yticks([p[1] for p in points])
plt.grid()
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: When you say "labels" do you mean the `xtick` and `ytick` labels? Or the axis titles/labels?

Comment: the xtick ytick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the gridline positions you want are distinct from all the tickmark positions you want, a simple way to do this is to use the minor ticks for the gridlines (assuming only the major ticks are to be shown as labeled tickmarks, as in your code).

Just replace `plt.grid()` in your code with this:

```py
ax.set_xticks(<list of vertical gridline positions>, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(<list of horizontal gridline positions>, minor=True)
plt.grid(which='minor')
```